# Library function generates "You do not have permission to call showModalDialog" error with installed trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, permissions

I have an Apps Script project where I'm using a single library to control multiple spreadsheets (one for each user).  This allows to me to keep all the code in one place for many users.

Each user's spreadsheet has an installable trigger (on edit) that runs as a single user with authorization and calls functions from the library.

I'm getting an error now that I wasn't before:

> "You do not have permission to call showModalDialog"

`showModalDialog` is indeed being used within the library to deliver alerts to the user using the spreadsheet.  I'm using `showModalDialog` rather than `ui.alert()` because `ui.alert()` stops the code and throws errors when the user doesn't respond after 5 minutes (say they walked away from their computer).  This was working before, but recently stopped working.  Why??

My script files include the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

Here's the code in the user-bound script:

```
function userEdited(e) {
  Library.userEdited(e);
}
```

the user-bound script has an installable trigger that runs "userEdited" with the "On edit" event.

Here is the code in the Library script:

```
function userEdited(e){
  alert("the dialogue works");
}

function alert(message){
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p>' + message + '</p>')
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(message.length / 50 * 25 + 30);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "HAL 9000");
}
```

Comment: If the library is accessed before the user has authorized the script scopes, you'll get errors during initialization. You have to check the `authMode` parameter before accessing your library. This is done intentionally to prevent scripts from opening content without the user initiating that action.

Comment: @Brian, I've never had to check the authMode before accessing a library... can you give me an example of how this is done?  I'm not getting auth errors for any other method I'm using in the library including using MailApp

Comment: The [`AuthMode` enum](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/auth-mode) determines how the script runs. Library scripts are loaded as globals, just like any global variable or Class you try to access when the script is loaded. So, if you have a method that requires authorization by the user, it will fail on initialization. You need to make sure the library isn't trying to access those properties or methods without user action in most cases.

Comment: Ok, so after reviewing the documentation for Authmode, I'm even more confused as to why showModalDialogue isn't working.  According to the documentation, the only reason the authmode would be NONE, or LIMITED would be if the script excutes from a simple trigger.  But I am using the onEdit installable trigger which should have full authorization to run anything right?  The only limitation I've been able to find in the documentation on installable triggers is that prompts like showModalDialogue and the sidebar can not be invoked from the onOpen installable trigger.  But thats not what I'm using.

Comment: It appears that checking the AuthMode is to prevent errors?  So if AuthMode is limited, then don't call this method.  But if it's not limited, then go ahead and call it.  Am I wrong?  Is there a way to allow showModalDialog to run from the library when invoked from the onEdit installable trigger?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Even though `onEdit()` is an Installable trigger, if you have an `onEdit` function it runs as a simple trigger, which could be causing the error. You need to post some code to get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: It is always desirable to name a function that receives an installed trigger a name that does not also bind the simple trigger

Comment: I updated the question to include the sample code that is throwing the error.  The function that I'm calling from the installable trigger is indeed named something other than the simple onEdit function.

Comment: Can anyone help me out here?  I've hit a dead end and not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: @Brian any additional thoughts?

Comment: @Rubén the code has been added.

Comment: Alex, can you confirm that passing the ui from the user sheet as a parameter to the library function still generates the issue? Is your library code in a bound script that the users do not have edit access to? i.e.: `function userEdit(e) { library.userEdit(e, SpreadsheetApp.getUi()); }`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a reason why showModalDialog isn't working, but I have found a work-around.  I am using [SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String)) and/or [Browser.msgBox()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgBox(String)) for now which doesn't throw any permission errors even during on open (installable trigger).  It's still not ideal because these methods do suspend the server-side script, leading to the possibility of the script timing out after 5 minutes if the user walks away from the computer.

According to the apps script documentation, there isn't any reason I can find that showModalDialogue would be throwing permission errors when called from an installable trigger. It would be really nice to have a dialogue method that would not stop the server-side script.